# Can we create a Child (with interface MyView extends PopupView) that inherit a PresenterWidget (with interface MyView extends View) (GWTP)?

Tags: gwtp

In GWTP, is there any way that we can create a Child (that has "interface MyView extends PopupView") that inherit  a PresenterWidget (that has "interface MyView extends View")?

Here is my problem. I have a need to prompt (in a form of PopupView) user to enter shipping address if they didn't have one.

Of course, there is a `UserShippingAddressPresenter` presenter widget that is not a popup & locates in profile page.

```
public class UserShippingAddressPresenter extends
    PresenterWidget<UserShippingAddressPresenter.MyView> {
    public interface MyView extends View {
    ////...... more code///

    }    
}
```

Now I want to have a `PopupUserShippingAddressPresenter` that has exactly Gui & functionality like the  `UserShippingAddressPresenter`, but it is a Popup like this

```
public class UserShippingAddressPopupPresenter extends
    PresenterWidget<UserShippingAddressPresenter.MyView> {
    public interface MyView extends PopupView {
    ////...... more code///

    }    
}
```

So This is the logic that i think it works but it didn't. That is I will use eclipse to create  `UserShippingAddressPopupPresenter` with `interface MyView extends PopupView` then in `UserShippingAddressPopupView` I tried to setInSlot userShiopingAddress like the following

```
public class UserShippingAddressPopupView extends PopupViewImpl implements
    UserShippingAddressPopupPresenter.MyView {
    @Override
    public void setInSlot(Object slot, Widget content){

       if(slot==ProfilePresenter.SLOT_userShippingAddress){
          userShippingAddressHTMLPanel.clear();
          if(content!=null){
               userShippingAddressHTMLPanel.add(content);
          }
       }
       else{
           super.setInSlot(slot, content);
       }
    }

}
```

in `UserShippingAddressPopupPresenter`

```
public class UserShippingAddressPopupPresenter extends
    PresenterWidget<UserShippingAddressPopupPresenter.MyView> {

    public static final Object SLOT_userShippingAddress=new Object();
    public interface MyView extends PopupView {}


    @Inject UserShippingAddressPresenter userShippingAddressPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onReveal() {
        super.onReveal();
        setInSlot( SLOT_userShippingAddress, userShippingAddressPresenter);
    }
}
```

After running, it showed a very small box in the middle of the page.

I tried `onReset` instead of `onReveal` but it didn't work either.
Can u find a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

My logic is ok, it's working. I fixed it, the problem is that "`if(slot==ProfilePresenter.SLOT_userShippingAddress){`" is wrong, correct should be "`if(slot==PopupUserShippingAddressPresenter.SLOT_userShippingAddress){`"